# I am getting an error while computing the compound interest

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
echo "Enter the principal value -> " 
read P
echo "Enter the rate of intrest -> " 
read R
echo "Enter the number of years -> " 
read t
echo "Enter the number of times applied per year ->"
read n

echo "The principal ,rate of interest and number of years are $P $R $t"
s=`echo $P \* $R \* $t \* 0.01 | bc -l`
echo "The simple Interest is $s"
amt=`echo "scale=2;$P * ( 1 + $R * $t )"  | bc -l`
echo "The amount is $amt"
power=`expr $n \* $t`
echo $power
ci=`echo "scale=2;$P * ( 1 + $r / $n ) ^ $power" | bc`
echo "The compound intrest is $ci"
```

**(standard_in) 1: syntax error**
I am getting this error while executing the code. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Assign a value to `$r`.

Comment: adding to @Cyrus comment ... cut-n-paste your code into [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/), scroll to the bottom of the output, and you'll see `SC2154: r is referenced but not assigned.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `ci='echo "scale=2;$P * ( 1 + $r / $n ) ^ $power" | bc'` you are trying to access `$r` but you only define `$R`.

This should fix it

```sh
ci='echo "scale=2;$P * ( 1 + $R / $n ) ^ $power" | bc'
```

Or assign a value to `r`